# Do chilli peppers change in composition after they change color?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, plant-physiology, fruit

I grow some chilli peppers and was wondering when the time is right to harvest them. Of course gardening-focused sources say that they are ripe when they change color. This usually happens very quickly (1-2 days) after a long period when they remain green (1-2 months), which would suggest that the gardening advice might be right.

However, I would like to know the full story, so I tried to find some relevant research. Here's what I found so far (mostly paywalled, sadly, so I cannot read the details)

[Development of pepper (Capsicum annuum) seed quality](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1744-7348.1992.tb03452.x)
Quite unrelated, but suggests that the end of the ripening process is not simply the end of it all

[Variations in germination and longevity of pepper (Capsicum annuum L.) seeds harvested at different stages of maturation](https://akjournals.com/view/journals/014/50/2/article-p157.xml)
Similar to the above, seeds still continue to change while the pepper changes color

[Changes in Carotenoid Esterification during the Fruit Ripening of Capsicum annuum Cv. Bola](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jf00039a007)
New carotenoids are produced during ripening

[Formation and transformation of pigments during the fruit ripening of Capsicum annuum Cv. Bola and Agridulce](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jf00037a005)
More information on the above

[Carotenoid Biosynthesis Changes in Five Red Pepper (Capsicum annuum L.) Cultivars during Ripening. Cultivar Selection for Breeding](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jf991020r)
[Carotenoid Composition in the Fruits of Capsicum annuum Cv. Szentesi Kosszarvú during Ripening](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jf950354n)
Researchers were apparently really interested in carotenoids in the 90s...

[Variation in phenolic compounds, ascorbic acid and antioxidant activity of five coloured bell pepper (Capsicum annum) fruits at two different harvest times](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1756464611000077)
This one suggests that there are still some changes happening after ripening: *With advanced maturation, total antioxidant activity increased, however some antioxidant components such as ascorbic acid, total phenols decreased.*

[The influence of fruit ripening on the phytochemical content and biological activity of Capsicum chinense Jacq. cv Habanero](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0308814608011771)
This one, while apparently full of interesting data, only deals with two stages of ripening(immature and mature).

[Ripening of pepper (Capsicum annuum) fruit is characterized by an enhancement of protein tyrosine nitration](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4577987/)
Very promising, but once again, research ends at the color change.

[Evolution of total and individual capsaicinoids in peppers during ripening of the Cayenne pepper plant (Capsicum annuum L.)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260013848_Evolution_of_total_and_individual_capsaicinoids_in_peppers_during_ripening_of_the_Cayenne_pepper_plant_Capsicum_annuum_L)
The only article which actually deals with peppers which were left to ripen a bit more. Capsaicin content decreases as the pepper ripens, followed by an increase when it's over-ripe. Weird, but at least I was able to legally obtain this article. Unfortunately it deals with capsaicinoids only.

**Is there more information about what happens to the chillies after they are ripe? I'm not really interested in heat, but rather in other chemicals which affect flavor and nutritional properties of chilli peppers.**

Edit: Based on what I observe at home, the peppers do indeed seem to be changing for at least a week or so after the change in color. I left some red chillies on the tree and their color is now noticeably darker than those which have just ripened a few days ago.

Comment: I welcome answers here, but this might be a case where it's best to do your own research a bit: you have an experiment already in place, so harvest at different points and see what you think.

Comment: @BryanKrause Of course I'm trying in the absence of reliable outside information, but my sample size is very small and this could take a long time, so I'd rather trust a scientific source than my own crappy research. The chillies I keep on the plant seem to not change very much anymore. I also read that keeping them on slows down the development of other fruit, which would support the hypothesis that there are still some resources being used by the ripe fruit.

Comment: When ripe the seeds become viable too.